# Surprising output using Parallel gem with srand and rand

Tags: ruby, random, parallel-processing

I'm working with ruby 2.4.1 + parallel 1.11.2. I'm running the following in irb:

```
require 'parallel'
srand(1)
Parallel.map([0, 1], in_processes: 2) { |i| puts "in process #{i}; rand => #{rand}" }
```

My understanding is that when `in_processes` is specified, `Parallel.map` forks the process and then executes the loop body. Given that, I expect both processes to have the same global state and therefore I had expected that both would output the same random number. However, here's what I get:

```
irb(main):003:0> Parallel.map([0, 1], in_processes: 2) { |i| puts "in process #{i}; rand => #{rand}" }
in process 1; rand => 0.48721687007281356
in process 0; rand => 0.7502824863668285
=> [nil, nil]
```

For the record, if I execute `srand(1)` and then `rand`, I get 0.417022004702574, so it appears that neither process got the random number seed which I set. I can get the behavior I want by setting the random number seed within the loop, but before I do that I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work to put the seed outside the loop.

I'm trying to make sense of this situation. Is this behavior somehow specific to the random number generator, so I wouldn't necessarily have the same problem (namely, expected shared initial state and didn't get it) with other objects? Or is Parallel not really having the same effect as a plain `fork` system call?

The documentation about Parallel with `in_processes` led me to believe that it acted like `fork`, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, hence my surprise.

EDIT: Some more experimenting shows that the same behavior arises when using `Process.fork`, so the problem has to do with `fork` and not the Parallel gem.

```
$ cat foo.rb
srand(1)
pid = Process.fork
if !pid
then puts "child says rand => #{rand}"
else puts "parent says rand => #{rand}"
Process.wait(pid)
end

$ ruby foo.rb
parent says rand => 0.417022004702574
child says rand => 0.7054895237863591
```

EDIT: Further investigation seems to show that the option `isolation: true` is relevant here. When accessing a variable in the parent process, `isolation: true` seems to have the desired effect.

```
irb(main):037:0> foo = 1;
irb(main):038:0* Parallel.map([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], in_processes: 2) { |i| puts "in process #{i}; foo = #{foo}"; foo = foo + 1 }
in process 0; foo = 1
in process 2; foo = 2
in process 3; foo = 3
in process 4; foo = 4
in process 5; foo = 5
in process 1; foo = 1
=> [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
irb(main):039:0> foo = 1;
irb(main):040:0* Parallel.map([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], in_processes: 2, isolation: true) { |i| puts "in process #{i}; foo = #{foo}"; foo = foo + 1 }
in process 1; foo = 1
in process 0; foo = 1
in process 2; foo = 1
in process 3; foo = 1
in process 4; foo = 1
in process 5; foo = 1
=> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

But `isolation: true` doesn't seem to have the desired effect on `rand`. Still don't understand what's going on there.

```
irb(main):032:0> srand(1);
irb(main):033:0* Parallel.map([0, 1], in_processes: 2) { |i| puts "in process #{i}; rand => #{rand}" }
in process 0; rand => 0.6837528723167413
in process 1; rand => 0.1469087219402977
=> [nil, nil]
irb(main):034:0> srand(1);
irb(main):035:0* Parallel.map([0, 1], in_processes: 2) { |i| puts "in process #{i}; rand => #{rand}" }
in process 0; rand => 0.7906373908366543
in process 1; rand => 0.8807214141308389
=> [nil, nil]
```

Comment: `rand()` is utter garbage. Don't use it. Any questions about why it's not working or why it's not producing good data is **because it's junk**. It's not thread safe in any fashion at all. Use [SecureRandom](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: Um, the question is more about Parallel. Anyway Ruby's built-in rng is a Mersenne twister implementation, which isn't "garbage".

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `rand()` which depends on global state. Instead use `SecureRandom` or if you need predictable sequences, `Random`:

```
seed = 1
generators = Array.new(2) { Random.new(seed) }

Parallel.map([0, 1], in_processes: 2) do |i|
  puts "in process #{i}; rand => #{generators[i].rand}"
end
```

This gives consistent output:

```
in process 1; rand => 0.417022004702574
in process 0; rand => 0.417022004702574
```

This is just one more reason why you shouldn't use `rand()`.

Comment: I don't understand why one would complain about `rand` and then recommend `Random`, since `rand` is an alias for `Random::DEFAULT.rand`.

Comment: I'm saying that `rand` is pretty weak, but if you're okay with that, then `Random` is your solution. It side-steps one of the multitude of problems that `Kernel#rand` has, and that problem is what's causing your issue.

Comment: `rand` isn't weak, and anyway number theoretic stuff like the period and entropy, etc, isn't coming into play here.

Comment: So long as you know the risks and you're okay with that. This is your call, after all, I'm just raising a warning here because `rand` is easily mistaken for being a lot more robust (e.g. cryptographically random) than it is.